# some Font Awesome icons not showing in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, font-awesome

Some Font Awesome icons (v4.7) are not displayed in Chrome (not even in the fontawesome.com webpage) - plz see attachment. It seems the `::before` is completely missing. The icons are correctly displayed in FireFox.
Please any ideas why this happens? Thanks.

[image: The attached image shows that the <code>::before</code> element on the <i> tag is completely missing for some of the icons]

Comment: You should write your code here, don't add a screen shot of your code.

Comment: @MohamadShahrestani well, the main thing I wanted to show is that the icons are not displayed (which I had to do using an image), and that it indeed happens in the FA page itself. The bit of code in the right is just to show a bit more detail

Comment: Okay that's cool

Comment: That is strange. I have tested https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/icons/ in Chrome 77 and the icons all display for me. If you are asking for a workaround then you could explicitly add `.fa-share:before {content: "\f064";}` to your own CSS to force it to display on your own site. The other thing to note is that FontAwesome 5 has been out for a long time now.

Comment: @MikePoole yes, it is strange... the issue still persists, i suspect it must be some kind of setting in my particular Chrome instance, but I'm not aware of making any modification that could be causing it.
thanks for the workaround, although as long as it works correctly in customers' browsers it's rather a matter of curiosity for me.
as for Font Awesome, we still use 4.7 because of the changes in pricing policy for version 5

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Ad-Blocker or similar?

We had a user report this very same issue - most icons worked but share and share-alt icons wouldn't. Couldn't replicate the issue on Chrome until we figured the user had Ad-Blocker running. Got them to add the site to the whitelist and the problem went away.